# Alarm Manager not scheduling alarm properly

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, repeatingalarm

I am setting alarm usng this

```
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,21);
    alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
    if (alarm.before(now)) {
        alarm.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  //Add 1 day if time selected before now
    }
         AlarmManager alarmManager =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context,Receiver.class);
   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,(int)alarm.getTimeInMillis(),i,0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (int)alarm.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pi);
```

But even if I schedule it for next day,it triggers immediately after saving alarm.
Dont know what the issue is have searched a lot but everyone else gets it working

Comment: M already adding a day if the time passes

Comment: No its not working it triggers immediately as it is set

Comment: Why are you casting to `int`?

Comment: ohh so sorie actually was casting int for pending intent.Thanks alot its not triggering immediately

Comment: Ya it didn't triggered immediately ,but when I tested today it didn't triggered at the scheduled time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting a `long` timestamp to `int` thus losing bits and changing the actual timestamp value. You end up with a time that already has passed so it executes the intent immediately.

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Notice that I removed the `(int)` cast in the last line.

Comment: I changed it and it didn't triggered immediately ,but it's not even getting triggered at the scheduled time